# Are all the open sets in a Euclidean space homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

I know that open balls are homeomorphic to the entire Euclidean space, and any convex open set can be proved to be homeomorphic to the entire Euclidean space. So I was wondering if *all* the open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are homeomorphic?

Comment: No ... there are for example disconnected open sets ...

Comment: Even with connected sets, they might have different kinds of "holes" in them.

Comment: This is not the only obstruction. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427787/characterization-of-the-subsets-of-euclidean-space-which-are-homeomorphic-to-the?rq=1 for the exact obstructions for open subsets to be homeomorphic to the space itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. For example, the open annulus
$$\{(x, y) \in \Bbb R^2 : 1 < x^2 + y^2 < 2\}$$
is not simply connected, but the open ball
$$\{(x, y) \in \Bbb R^2 : x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$$
is.